# Intune vs Registry key and spaces in path

Tags: powershell, intune, registrykey

I am trying to run script that would return me work or school account connected to the device. The script should be distributed over Intune. Everything elser works except this part.
The code works in local powershell.

```
$path = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WorkplaceJoin\JoinInfo'
Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Get-ItemPropertyValue | Select-Object UserEMail | select UserEmail | ft -HideTableHeaders | out-string
```

But when it's published to intune then it ends with error, that in the path is space (between Windows and NT)

> Cannot find path 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows \r\nNT\CurrentVersion\WorkplaceJoin\JoinInfo' because it does not exist.

I've also tried this code

```
$x=(dsregcmd /status | select-string -Pattern "WorkplaceThumbprint" | out-string).Trim()
$y=$x.LastIndexOf(":")
$AccountThumbPrint=$x.Substring($y+2)
$AccountMailAddress=(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WorkplaceJoin\JoinInfo\$AccountThumbPrint" -Name UserEmail | select UserEmail | ft -HideTableHeaders | out-string).Trim()

Write-Host "$AccountMailAddress"
```

ending with the same error.

I think I've tried almost everything what could be found on google
like Single quote marks, double quote marks

Thank you

edit:
full code I am running to all Windows devices connected in itune:

```
## setting variables
$cpu = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor  |  select @{n="ComputerName";e={$_.systemname}},@{n="CPU";e={$_.name}}
$model = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Model,Manufacturer
$serialNumber = Get-WmiObject win32_bios | Select-Object SerialNumber
$WinVer = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Version
$WinBuild = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object BuildNumber
$memory = (Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory  | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Capacity).Sum / (1024*1024*1024)
$owner = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object PrimaryOwnerName
$totalStorage = (Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Size).Sum / (1000*1000*1000)   

## this is not used, but it was taken as an example
## variables to get work or school account connected to "Current user"
##  $x=(dsregcmd /status | select-string -Pattern "WorkplaceThumbprint" | out-string).Trim()
##  $y=$x.LastIndexOf(":")
##  $AccountThumbPrint=$x.Substring($y+2)
$path = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WorkplaceJoin\JoinInfo'
##Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Get-ItemPropertyValue | Select-Object UserEMail | select UserEmail | ft -HideTableHeaders | out-string

## getting the mail itself
$AccountMailAddress = (Get-ChildItem $path | Get-ItemProperty).UserEmail

                                                                                                                                          
[PSCUStOMOBJECT]@{
    "ComputerName"=$env:COMPUTERNAME;
    "Model"=$model.Model;
    "SerialNumber"=$serialNumber.SerialNumber;
    "Owner"=$owner.PrimaryOwnerName;
    "Work or School account" = $AccountMailAddress;
    "Windows Version" = $WinVer.Version;
    "Windows Build" = $WinBuild.BuildNumber;
    "RAM(GB)"=$memory;
    "CPU"=$cpu.CPU;
    "TotalCStorage"=$totalStorage
    } | ConvertTo-Json
```

I've obtained example from https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/device-management-in-microsoft/how-to-collect-custom-inventory-from-azure-ad-joined-devices/ba-p/2280850

Comment: Somewhat suspiciously, the error suggests the inclusion of `\r\n` in your path, this would indicate a NewLine between `Windows` and `NT`, if you've been copy and pasting this value, it might have included this hidden character the entire time. Copy and paste the path directly from RegEdit again to ensure the character is removed.

Comment: As an aside: Your command can be simplified to `(Get-ChildItem $path | Get-ItemProperty).UserEmail`

Comment: `"EncryptMsg":"run in legacy mode","ExecutionMsg":"Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows \r\nNT\\CurrentVersion\\WorkplaceJoin\\JoinInfo' because it does not exist.\r\nAt C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Intune Management \r\nExtension\\Policies\\....ps1:3 char:2\r\n+ (Get-ChildItem $path | Get-ItemProperty).UserEmail\r\n+ ~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (HKEY_CURRENT_US...ceJoin\\JoinInfo:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFound \r\n  Exception\r\n + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand\r\n \r\n\r\n"}`

Comment: I understand that space is limited in comments, but please don't delete parts that can make a crucial difference. We're back to square one: without seeing how your PowerShell Code is invoked, your problem cannot be diagnosed. If the code is called by passing a _string_ containing PowerShell code to PowerShell's _CLI_ (`powershell.exe` (WinPS) or `pwsh -c` (PowerShell Core)), note that `"` chars. meant to be part of the code must be escaped as ``\"``

Comment: I have added full code to the top under "edit".
As we are using cloud service, all the data comes back to me correctly except the mail. That's because of the space.

Comment: I still don't know how to solve this. I've read multiple articles about similar issues and neither was working for me.
Tried solutions:
`&`, `\"`, `/"`, `Set-Location HKCU:`....still ending on the issue with `Windows \r\nNT`

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, the symptom cannot be explained. Perhaps an InTune subject-matter expert can _infer_ what the problem is, but there's no telling if and when that will happen.

Comment: Thanks anyway!!! I appreciate it a lot!